# Response code is null while executing Axis2 webservice client in java but webservice executed successfully at the server end

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservices-client

I am working on axis2 webservice in java for insertion of records into database. i am testing the webservice client, it return null response code, actually i return integer value in webservice but i inserted the records in database successfully, i can able to see in my databnase while executing the client but it return null instead of integer response code 100.whenever i see the log file in server side, no exception rises.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue, i resolved it through message inspector.

Implement message inspector `IClientMessageInspector` capture and correct your response at `AfterReceiveReply`

Please provide your response to help you.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion pointed me to the right direction. I have captured the request and clean it before de-serializing.